# ASP.NET 4.6 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'YES' to data type int

Tags: c#, webforms, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-4.6

Please help as this is a time sensitive issue I'm having with a project.  The problem is that I have a GridView and in that GridView I have one column that requires a 'YES' or 'NO' response.  I'm using a dropdownlist in the EditItemTemplate to grab distinct or unique choices from the database.  Everything loads and displays fine from the datasource as you can see in this picture:

[image: GridView from datasource when page loads]

When I click the edit button the fields display appropriately as well as you can see from this picture:

[image]

However, when I select either 'YES' or 'NO', and click Update; I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the snippet of my .aspx code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Required" SortExpression="IsRequired">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="dsIsRequiredDDL" DataTextField="IsRequired" DataValueField="IsRequired"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsIsRequiredDDL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BITSDevConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [IsRequired] FROM [EmpCertType]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IsRequired") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

And he is a picture of the table in my database:

[image]

For the record, all data in the database is test (fictitious) data so there are no PII concerns.

So the questions are: What is going on?  Why am I getting this error?  And most importantly, how do I correct this?

I've tried using a radiobuttonlist and got an error with that as well. I've tried hard coding the selections in the dropdownlist and got the same error I got here, and I've done hours and hours of research on this one problem alone.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would you use a string field for this?  Its just a boolean `Required:true|false` which is far better represented as a checkbox in a UI

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, and had I written the database that's exactly what I would have done.  However, I did not develop the DB so I have to work with what I was given.  Thank you though.  Hopefully that helps someone else.

Comment: Why no SelectedValue='<%# Bind ("IsRequired") %>' on the dropdown?